# Dealing with duplicate keys in codeigniter mysql insert

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

What I want to do is something like this:

```
function registerUser($username, $password){

$this->db->insert('tblUsers', array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>md5($password)));
if($this->db->_error_number()==1062){
    return "DUPLICATE";
}
return true;

}
```

However, at the moment if there is a duplicate key then its not letting me get to the `_error_number()` bit. Its displaying an error like this:

[image]

How do I stop codeigniter from bailing with an error and passing the error number to me to deal with appropriately?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access MySQL error messages in Codeigniter using:

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```

Apparently DB_DEBUG needs to be set to false in the database config file:

> Ensure DB_DEBUG is set to FALSE in the database config file, or
>   execution will halt when a mysql error occurs (it does not get thrown,
>   it justs exits from the php interpreter)

Link: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/79950/#413830

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I'm using _error_number() to get the error number in the code above. However, its not geting to there, its ditching before hand, and printing an error.

Comment: See my revised solution. Note that you will no longer be able to see the MySQL error messages without using _error_message()/_error_number()

Answer (score 8):

Suggestion:

```
$orig_db_debug = $this->db->db_debug;

$this->db->db_debug = FALSE;

RUN QUERY HERE

$this->db->db_debug = $orig_db_debug;
```